# How can I combine multiple queries? (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a question about combining several queries.

The original table is as follows. The first column is children’s height, the second column is the city where each child lives, and the third column is whether they are a boy or a girl. The table name is "data".

| height | city | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | x | 1 |
| 130 | x | 0 |
| 135 | x | 0 |
| 150 | x | 1 |
| 120 | x | 0 |
| 121 | y | 0 |
| 140 | y | 1 |
| 110 | y | 1 |
| 160 | y | 1 |
| 100 | z | 1 |
| 150 | z | 0 |
| 130 | z | 0 |
| 120 | z | 0 |
| 110 | z | 1 |
| 125 | z | 1 |

My teacher told us to find each city’s highest and lowest heights using SQL(Postgres).
The ideal output is as follows.

| max_min | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Max | 150 | 160 | 150 |
| Min | 120 | 110 | 100 |

My approach is
-1st step: Make a query for each city
-2nd step: Join these queries into one

I successfully made a query for each city's Max and Min. For example, my code and the output for city x is as follows.

-code

```
select * from (  
(select 'Max' max_min, height x  
from data  
where city in ('x')  
order by height desc limit 1)  
union  
(select 'Min' max_min, height x  
from data  
where city in ('x')  
order by height asc limit 1)  
)as tbl;
```

output

| max_min | x |
| --- | --- |
| Max | 150 |
| Min | 120 |

However, I am stuck in joining these queries. Could you please teach me how to get the ideal output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add conditional aggregation:

```
select 'Max' max_min,
max(case when city = 'x' then height end) x,
max(case when city = 'y' then height end) y,
max(case when city = 'z' then height end) z
from t1
union all
select 'Min' max_min,
min(case when city = 'x' then height end) x,
min(case when city = 'y' then height end) y,
min(case when city = 'z' then height end) z
from t1
```

here is an example: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iXB4WAuDTyPzYE1pRqinPH/14)

Comment: Thanks to your code, I found the right answer which meets requirements.
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I would aggregate and then use a lateral join to split the rows:

```
select v.*
from (select min(height) filter (where city = 'x') as x_min,
             min(height) filter (where city = 'y') as y_min,
             min(height) filter (where city = 'z') as z_min,
             max(height) filter (where city = 'x') as x_max,
             max(height) filter (where city = 'y') as y_max,
             max(height) filter (where city = 'z') as z_max             
      from data d
     ) d cross join lateral 
     (values ('min', x_min, y_min, z_min), ('max', x_max, y_max, z_max)
     ) v(which, x, y, z);
     (values ('min'), ('max')) v(which);
```

This structure for the query only does the aggregation once which is performance win.  If the "table" is really a complicated query, the performance gain can be significant.

Comment: Thanks to your code, I found the right answer which meets requirements.
I appreciate your help!